# Angular One time binding still has watchers on it

Tags: angularjs, batarang, one-time-binding

I used a simple AngularJS interpolation with one-time binding.
The code works as expected and any further changes to that scope variable are not reflecting.
However, when I was checking the performance of my application using Batarang (Chrome extension), I observed that there are still watchers left on that interpolation

I'm not sure if I really achieved any performance gain using one-time binding.

Comment: Maybe you could provide a code example?

Answer (score 0):

I came across several hints in the web, stating that Batarang would not work with one time bindings. Therefore I deinstalled Batarang and used [angular watchers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-watchers/nlmjblobloedpmkmmckeehnbfalnjnjk?hl=en) instead (for angular 1.3.x), worked like a charm.